# How to verify if element has changed its value without adding browser.sleep?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In a protractor test we have to verify if an element has changed its value.

For example:

```
<div>aaa</div> has changed to <div>bbb</div>
```

`<div>` element always exists, only changes the value.

Due its asynchronous, protractor function  `element(locatorOfTheDiv).getText()` returns a promise, that always is fulfilled before aaa has changed to bbb (and then we get a false result)

How can verify if element has changed its value?

Is there any alternative to adding `browser.sleep(5000)`?

Comment: Does the change happens on an event or after specific amount of time?

Comment: @maurycy When user clicks on a button the value changes.(but sometimes does not changes immediately and there are a few seconds of delay).

Comment: In that case sleep is the only option, why it does take a few seconds to update the value?

Comment: @maurycy Well, it does not really matter. Could be because it is a value that has to be calculated, or because it depends of an external API, or whatever ... I've simplified the case for asking in S.O.

Comment: Try this

    expect(element(locatorOfTheDiv).getText()).toEqual('aaa');
    buttonElement.click().then(function() {
        expect(element(locatorOfTheDiv).getText()).toEqual('bbb');
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page is not doing anything asynchronous outside of the world of Angular, Protractor takes care of this for you automatically. You can just write:

```
var myDiv = element(by.css('div.foo'));
expect(myDiv.getText()).toEqual('aaa');
otherButton.click(); // Do whatever causes it to change here.
expect(myDiv.getText()).toEqual('bbb');
```

If the asynchronous code is outside of Angular, then Protractor has no way of knowing about it. In that case, you'll need to use a sleep or wait - generally waits are preferable since they keep checking until the value is changed.

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return myDiv.getText().then(function(text) {
    return text == 'bbb';
  });
}, 'waiting for div to have text bbb');
```